# OSX 10.13.4 'Sets up your Mac' every login

Tags: macos

I just upgraded to 10.13.4, and every time I reboot or login I get the "Setting up your Mac" screen. It also adds the default apps to the dock (such as Siri and Downloads folder). If I remove those two and log out or reboot, the next time I log in I get the same "Setting up your Mac" as well as the default apps again. This happens on two machines I have; a MacBook Pro and a Mac Pro.

Has anyone else seen this behavior and, more importantly, have a fix for it? Or is it just a bug in 10.13.4?

Comment: No such problem on my 10.3.4 Mac. You didn't leave a copy of the Installer in the App folder, did you? That might mess with startup. Neither Siri or Downloads folder are in my dock.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem for a while. One of the reasons may be third-party security software, e.g. [ESET Cyber Security](https://eset-support.canon-its.jp/faq/show/1601?category_id=9&site_domain=private).

Uninstalling it might work for you, though it didn't for me.
I've uninstalled ESET but mbp High Sierra still brings back icons (Siri, Maps, iBooks, Photos).